# Generate a test XML from XML Schema programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd, sample

I have searched for a bit now, but i'm not able to find a way to autogenerate data from a XML Schema programmatically. Lets say I have this XML schema:

```
<xs:element xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name ="Persons">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Person">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am able to create a XML from this using the VS function "Generate Sample XML"
[image]

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Edit: To specify. I do not want to create all the objects and insert data programmatically myself. I would like for it to create the objects and attributes automatically just like the "Generate Sample XML" in VS. The reason for this is that i would like to change the XSD without having to do anything about xml sample generation.

Comment: Inside or outside of VS? That is, you can do it programmatically within VS by writing a plug in that triggers this menu option.

Comment: preferably something independent of IDE. But I am open for all solutions VS dependent or not.

Comment: I have still not found a solution to this. So if anyone have any possible solutions, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after doing some searching. I have found a [project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx) that have implemented a  xml sample generator. I created a test solution and imported the classes. Then i deleted the XmlGen.cs file and created my own main method. The output will be based on the root element.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("schema.xsd")))
            {
                var schema = XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader.Create(stream ), null);
                var gen = new XmlSampleGenerator(schema, new XmlQualifiedName("rootElement"));
                gen.WriteXml(XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\temp\autogen.xml"));
                Console.WriteLine("Autogenerated file is here : c:\temp\autogen.xml");
            }            
        }
```

Comment: The link for the sample code was dead when I checked. There is a repository which seems to have the source in it though here - https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/tree/master/XmlSampleGenerator
Many thanks to the contributors :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can  write simple function for put 1 row into your data table and after that execute `DataTable.WriteXml(string filePath)`

Somethig like that:

```
xmlschema1 schema=new xmlschema1();
//put some test data in table
schema.Persons.AddPersonsRow(...some params);
//generate xml
schema.Persons.WriteXml(filePath);
```

Comment: does this generate a xml with sample data?

Comment: this will generate xml like <DocumentElement><Persons> ...some data </Persons> <Persons> ...some data </Persons> ...more Persons tags </DocumentElement>

Comment: But this is not autogenerated. I have to manually put inn all the objects. I would like to have some method that inserts data and creates sample objects automatically.