# Extract XPath from xsd Schema

Tags: c#, xsd

Wondering if it's possible!!

Given just an xsd schema is it possible to extract all the xpaths?

Using c# I Load an xsdSchema into an XDocument using linq to xml and then I must extract all  the xpaths.

Looked on the net but cannot find anything!

Comment: There are an infinite number of XPath expressions which can select elements in any given document, or set of documents.  What on earth would "all the xpaths" be?  Perhaps you have something concrete in mind; I wonder what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [MSDN article on how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675171)

---

To summarise the code from the article is:

> This example shows an function named GetXPath that generates a
>   specific XPath expression for any node in the XML tree. It generates
>   appropriate XPath expressions even when nodes are in a namespace. The
>   XPath expressions are generated by using namespace prefixes.
>
> ```
> public static class MyExtensions
> {
>     private static string GetQName(XElement xe)
>     {
>         string prefix = xe.GetPrefixOfNamespace(xe.Name.Namespace);
>         if (xe.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None || prefix == null)
>             return xe.Name.LocalName.ToString();
>         else
>             return prefix + ":" + xe.Name.LocalName.ToString();
>     }
>
>     private static string GetQName(XAttribute xa)
>     {
>         string prefix =
>             xa.Parent.GetPrefixOfNamespace(xa.Name.Namespace);
>         if (xa.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None || prefix == null)
>             return xa.Name.ToString();
>         else
>             return prefix + ":" + xa.Name.LocalName;
>     }
>
>     private static string NameWithPredicate(XElement el)
>     {
>         if (el.Parent != null && el.Parent.Elements(el.Name).Count() != 1)
>             return GetQName(el) + "[" +
>                 (el.ElementsBeforeSelf(el.Name).Count() + 1) + "]";
>         else
>             return GetQName(el);
>     }
>
>     public static string StrCat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
>         string separator)
>     {
>         return source.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
>                    (sb, i) => sb
>                        .Append(i.ToString())
>                        .Append(separator),
>                    s => s.ToString());
>     }
>
>     public static string GetXPath(this XObject xobj)
>     {
>         if (xobj.Parent == null)
>         {
>             XDocument doc = xobj as XDocument;
>             if (doc != null)
>                 return ".";
>             XElement el = xobj as XElement;
>             if (el != null)
>                 return "/" + NameWithPredicate(el);
>             // the XPath data model does not include white space text nodes
>             // that are children of a document, so this method returns null.
>             XText xt = xobj as XText;
>             if (xt != null)
>                 return null;
>             XComment com = xobj as XComment;
>             if (com != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     (
>                         com
>                         .Document
>                         .Nodes()
>                         .OfType<XComment>()
>                         .Count() != 1 ?
>                         "comment()[" +
>                         (com
>                         .NodesBeforeSelf()
>                         .OfType<XComment>()
>                         .Count() + 1) +
>                         "]" :
>                         "comment()"
>                     );
>             XProcessingInstruction pi = xobj as XProcessingInstruction;
>             if (pi != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     (
>                         pi.Document.Nodes()
>                         .OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()
>                         .Count() != 1 ?
>                         "processing-instruction()[" +
>                         (pi
>                         .NodesBeforeSelf()
>                         .OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()
>                         .Count() + 1) +
>                         "]" :
>                         "processing-instruction()"
>                     );
>             return null;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             XElement el = xobj as XElement;
>             if (el != null)
>             {
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     el
>                     .Ancestors()
>                     .InDocumentOrder()
>                     .Select(e => NameWithPredicate(e))
>                     .StrCat("/") +
>                     NameWithPredicate(el);
>             }
>             XAttribute at = xobj as XAttribute;
>             if (at != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     at
>                     .Parent
>                     .AncestorsAndSelf()
>                     .InDocumentOrder()
>                     .Select(e => NameWithPredicate(e))
>                     .StrCat("/") +
>                     "@" + GetQName(at);
>             XComment com = xobj as XComment;
>             if (com != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     com
>                     .Parent
>                     .AncestorsAndSelf()
>                     .InDocumentOrder()
>                     .Select(e => NameWithPredicate(e))
>                     .StrCat("/") +
>                     (
>                         com
>                         .Parent
>                         .Nodes()
>                         .OfType<XComment>()
>                         .Count() != 1 ?
>                         "comment()[" +
>                         (com
>                         .NodesBeforeSelf()
>                         .OfType<XComment>()
>                         .Count() + 1) + "]" :
>                         "comment()"
>                     );
>             XCData cd = xobj as XCData;
>             if (cd != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     cd
>                     .Parent
>                     .AncestorsAndSelf()
>                     .InDocumentOrder()
>                     .Select(e => NameWithPredicate(e))
>                     .StrCat("/") +
>                     (
>                         cd
>                         .Parent
>                         .Nodes()
>                         .OfType<XText>()
>                         .Count() != 1 ?
>                         "text()[" +
>                         (cd
>                         .NodesBeforeSelf()
>                         .OfType<XText>()
>                         .Count() + 1) + "]" :
>                         "text()"
>                     );
>             XText tx = xobj as XText;
>             if (tx != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     tx
>                     .Parent
>                     .AncestorsAndSelf()
>                     .InDocumentOrder()
>                     .Select(e => NameWithPredicate(e))
>                     .StrCat("/") +
>                     (
>                         tx
>                         .Parent
>                         .Nodes()
>                         .OfType<XText>()
>                         .Count() != 1 ?
>                         "text()[" +
>                         (tx
>                         .NodesBeforeSelf()
>                         .OfType<XText>()
>                         .Count() + 1) + "]" :
>                         "text()"
>                     );
>             XProcessingInstruction pi = xobj as XProcessingInstruction;
>             if (pi != null)
>                 return
>                     "/" +
>                     pi
>                     .Parent
>                     .AncestorsAndSelf()
>                     .InDocumentOrder()
>                     .Select(e => NameWithPredicate(e))
>                     .StrCat("/") +
>                     (
>                         pi
>                         .Parent
>                         .Nodes()
>                         .OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()
>                         .Count() != 1 ?
>                         "processing-instruction()[" +
>                         (pi
>                         .NodesBeforeSelf()
>                         .OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()
>                         .Count() + 1) + "]" :
>                         "processing-instruction()"
>                     );
>             return null;
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
>         XDocument doc = new XDocument(
>             new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
>             new XProcessingInstruction("target", "data"),
>             new XElement("Root",
>                 new XAttribute("AttName", "An Attribute"),
>                 new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "aw", aw.ToString()),
>                 new XComment("This is a comment"),
>                 new XElement("Child",
>                     new XText("Text")
>                 ),
>                 new XElement("Child",
>                     new XText("Other Text")
>                 ),
>                 new XElement("ChildWithMixedContent",
>                     new XText("text"),
>                     new XElement("b", "BoldText"),
>                     new XText("otherText")
>                 ),
>                 new XElement(aw + "ElementInNamespace",
>                     new XElement(aw + "ChildInNamespace")
>                 )
>             )
>         );
>         doc.Save("Test.xml");
>         Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("Test.xml"));
>         Console.WriteLine("------");
>         foreach (XObject obj in doc.DescendantNodes())
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(obj.GetXPath());
>             XElement el = obj as XElement;
>             if (el != null)
>                 foreach (XAttribute at in el.Attributes())
>                     Console.WriteLine(at.GetXPath());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer that works on an xml but not an xsd file.I suppose I must generate programmatically the xml from xsd and then call the xpath I suppose.Is that what you think too?

Comment: hi @user231465, yes, you can use a tool such as(http://www.xsd2xml.com/) to generate an XML from your XSD, then the above code should work.

Comment: Hi I need to do all programmatically do you know any tool or c# class that I can use to do that

Comment: You can't generate an XML from an XSD like that. An XSD only specifies what the data should look like (types, etc.) not what values are contained in the data. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394310/generate-a-test-xml-from-xml-schema-programmatically) talks about generating a sample XML from an XSD. If you combine the two you can probably generate something.

Comment: @Liam this is 90% there, (and probably 100% if .NET had implemented XPath 2.0).  There's a bug if you try to evaluate the QName-based expressions with an `XPathEvaluate` call.  To anyone else who runs into this: there are a couple workarounds (1) use an `IXmlNamespaceResolver` if you know what namespaces you need , or (2) use a compatible expression with `local-name` and `namespace-uri` functions instead of a QName string. +1