# Create XML from XSD with sample data in c# programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XSD schema in a local file on disk. This XSD can get updated any time, or changed with another one. So it is dynamic, and I can't grab it or keep somewhere.

**My goal** is to be able to get a list of all possible XML elements, with their respectful ancestor paths, printed out (in console) Example:

`Desired Console output:
Html
Head - Html
Style - Head - Html
Body - Html
div - Body - Html
p - div - Body - Html
span - div - Body - Html
strong - div - Body - Html`

Note: I am not using Actual Html DOM, I am using it to explain the hierarchy.

**Simple solution** (I hoped would work...) Parse XSD and filter all instances of elements that have **name="[anyHtmlTag]"**, this way I am able to get a list of all possible elements, but not paths to their Parents. My XSD uses  that refers to a type that is located somewhere deeper in XSD, here is a brief example:
[image: My XSD Example]

**Problem** is that because I am in **Sequence**, "span", "p" or "strong" property cannot see it's parent "div" in this case.

`Actual result that is not desired
Html
Head - Html
Style - Head - Html
Body - Html
div - Body - Html
p
span 
strong`

The reason why It can't see it, is because I am parsing (in C#) XSD schema as if it would be XML document.

In this way I always expect that as hierarchy goes deeper, it will always see it's ancestor.

So my code here works pretty good, until it hits the **Sequence reference** in XSD, and it gets the element, but fails to get it's ancestors.

**C# code example**

```
public List<string> GetAllXmlPaths(out List<ValidationResult> errors)
    {
        errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
        List<string> foundPaths = new List<string>();
        string path = @"C:\temp\XSD.xsd"; // this is dynamic
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
        XmlSchema myschema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, ValidationCallback);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        myschema.Write(sw);
        string XSD = sw.ToString();
        var xs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(XSD);
        foreach (var element in doc.Descendants(xs + "element"))
        {
            // check ancestors
            string pathToTheTop = "";                
            if (element.Ancestors(xs + "element").Any())
            {
                foreach (var p in element.Ancestors(xs + "element"))
                {
                    pathToTheTop = pathToTheTop+ "\\" + p.Attribute("name").Value;
                }
            }
            foundPaths.Add(element.Attribute("name").Value + ":" + pathToTheTop);
            Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("name").Value + ":" + pathToTheTop);
        }
        return foundPaths;
    }
```

**Why I need to create XML?** In my opinion so far, solution would be to programmatically create a XML with sample data (does not matter what data) but it has to generate XML with all possible paths that XSD provides. In this way all ancestors would be present, and I could parse all hierarchy with ease.

VS has a build-in feature, that allows you to right-click and generate a sample XML out of XSD via **XMLSchemaExplorer**. more info here: [Generate a test XML from XML Schema programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394310/generate-a-test-xml-from-xml-schema-programmatically) So I need exact same functionality, but do that programmatically (while I am still in my run-time).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394310/generate-a-test-xml-from-xml-schema-programmatically

Comment: Hi Tom, In part where I explained "Why I need to create XML?" I included exact same link. I also mentioned, that I need to accomplish the same task, but do it programmatically (during runtime).

Comment: Ok I should have read your question property then!